# How do I get the row of a ListView when I edit text in a TextBox inside that row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Like the title states, I'm wondering how I would get the row/item when I edit a bound `TextBox` that is part of that row/item?

It seems like unless I manually select the row before hand, calling `<ListView>.SelectedIndex` will just net me `-1` and `<ListView>.SelectedItem` is `null` (both of which technically makes sense).

Below is my `ListView`'s current setup.

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeListView" Height="108" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style>
   <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <ListView.View>
  <GridView>
   <GridViewColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Header="Name" Width="100">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox x:Name="EmployeeNameTextBox" Margin="6,-1,-6,-1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" TextChanged="EmployeeNameTextBox_TextChanged"/>
     </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn x:Name="job_TitleColumn" Header="Job Title" Width="170">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox x:Name="EmployeeJobTitleTextBox" Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding JobTitle, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" TextChanged="EmployeeJobTitleTextBox_TextChanged"/>
     </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt your item container style to select the item whenever the keyboard focus is within.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I don't know if this answer is technically the better one, but I love how it just works.

Answer (score 0):

In the textchanged event handler of the text box you can get the DataContext of the TextBox (sender), which will be the underlying item.

Or you can use the VisualTreeHelper to find the parent ListViewItem.